# SfB client does not receive message,if Message is sent from bot to SfB,if SfB window is minimized, not in Right corner,has multiple conversation added

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

SfB client does not receive message, when Message is sent from bot to SfB client, if SfB client window is minimized, or not in Right-Down corner of screen, or has multiple conversation added in SfB client.

**Bot Info**

SDK Platform: Node.js

botbuilder Version: 3.8.4

Active Channels: Skype for Business

Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service, Azure App Service

Issue Description

We have created a bot for Skype for Business to start conversation with SFB clients. In our case, when conversation is initiated from bot using following code, SFB client does not receive the message from bot if -
user has minimized SFB window,
OR
if SFB client window is not near right-lower corner of the screen.
OR
If then only it is able to receive the message from bot.
OR
if user has multiple conversation added in the SFB client,

SFB client receives the message from Bot if -
User has it SFB window in right -Down corner of the screen, and it has only one coversation (i.e Conversation with Bot) in the SFB client window.

```
    var restify = require('restify');
    var builder = require('botbuilder');

    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
    });

    // Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
    var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: //GUID,
    appPassword: password,
    stateEndpoint: process.env.BotStateEndpoint,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
    });

    // Listen for messages from users
    server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

    var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();

    // Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
    var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector)
    .set('storage', inMemoryStorage);

    let addr1 =
    {
    channelId: 'skypeforbusiness',
    user: {
    id: 'sip:xyz@abcd.com'
    },
    channelData: {
    tenant: {
    id: //GUID
    }
    },
    bot:
    {
    id: 'sip:botid@abcd.com',
    name: 'BotName'
    },
    serviceUrl: 'https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/platformservice/botframework/'
    };

    bot.loadSession(addr1, function (err, session) {
    session.send('hi00');
    });

    bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

**Reproduction Steps**

Minimize the SFB client window.

Start bot to initiate the conversation , and send the message to SFB client .
OR
Add another conversation to SFB client (with another contact except BOT).
Start bot and initiate the conversation from bot to send the message to SFB client.

In our case we stat debugging in VSCode and attaching debugger to NGRok )

**Expected Behavior**

When Bot is started , SFB client must receive message sent from the bot, whether client window in minimized, or it has multiple conversation adde , or SFB client window it is anywhere on the screen .

**Actual Results**

When message is sent from the Bot, if SFB client window is not in Right-Down corner of screen,or if user has multiple conversation in SFB client window, It does not receive the message from Bot.

**error messages. -->**
There are no error messages seen while running the bot.